# Horizontal StackPanel Scroll view for Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, uwp

Basically I'm trying to create a scroll view on top of the page which will hold all days (like Saturday Sunday etc) which can be scrolled through horizontally. Here's my `MainPage.xaml` -

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Get_Weather"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ViewModel="using:Get_Weather.ViewModel"
x:Class="Get_Weather.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MainViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="ItemsPanelTemplate1"/>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <GridViewItem Content="Saturday"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="Sunday"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="Monday"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="Tuesday"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="Wednesday"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="Thrusday"/>
            <GridViewItem Content="Friday"/>



        </ListBox>
    </Grid>


</Grid>
</Page>
```

Initially I was trying to use `DataBindings` as in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zm2tOtr8ReM) using `MVVM` but unfortunately it appears it doesn't work for `UWP` as it was in `WPF` and hence when I run the project it doesn't display anything! So I decided to go old school and hardcode it!
Pretty new to this so help would be appreciated!

Comment: Tried setting `<VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" CanHorizontallyScroll="True"/>` but it gives an error `XBF generation error code 0x09c4` and `The Property CanHorizontallyScroll was not found in VirtualizingStackPanel`

Answer (score 0):

ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode needs to be set to Auto.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto">
    <ListBox.Resources>
```